# Утечка памяти при использовании Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, память, vuex, утечка-памяти

Пишу MMO RTS. На фронте использую Vue. С заданной периодичностью, с сервера, по WebSoket, прилетают обновленные данные. Естественно, данные помещаются во Vuex, за которым следят компоненты.

Обнаружил, что с каждым новым коммитом увеличивается потребление памяти. Если оставить вкладку открытой, то браузер вылетает.

Ниже код демонстрирующий проблему: запустите, откройте консоль - вкладка Memory -  и наблюдайте

```js
const data = {
  lvl: 0,
  a: {
    lvl: 1,
    b: {
      lvl: 2,
      c: {
        lvl: 3
      }
    }
  }
}
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0,
    data: []
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.count++;
    },
    set_data(state, payload) {
      state.data = payload;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    increment(context) {
      setInterval(() => {
        context.commit('increment');
        const newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        context.commit('set_data', newData);
      }, 500);
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  template: `
  <div>{{count}}</div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      d: window.performance.memory.totalJSHeapSize
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('increment');
  },
  watch: {
    '$store.state.data': {
      deep: true,
      handler() {
        this.count = this.$store.state.count;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.1/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@2.0.0"></script>
    <div id="app"></div>
```

Новость для меня печальная). Четкого понимания, как решить проблему - пока нет.

**UPD**
Обнаружился нюанс: если html-файл, с этим примером, открыть не через сервер, а полному пути в адресной строке, то утечки нет.

Comment: https://habr.com/en/post/449368/ — похоже на то)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, ну не знаю. Сомневаюсь. Данные у меня приходят в виде сериализованого JSON, который я потом превращаю в объект и передаю в store. Никаких строк у меня не остается. Даже если мой пример переписать и использовать 1 из способов, указанных в статье `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(str));` - все равно будет утечка

Comment: Кстати, утечки не будет, если в мутации, перед присвоением написать `delete state.data`... Но тогда и компоненты не видят изменений

Comment: У меня пример нормально отрабатывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось,проблема была во Vuex. Если подключить последнюю версию (3.1.2), то это убирает утечку в моем демо-примере.

```js
const data = {
  lvl: 0,
  a: {
    lvl: 1,
    b: {
      lvl: 2,
      c: {
        lvl: 3
      }
    }
  }
}
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0,
    data: []
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.count++;
    },
    set_data(state, payload) {
      state.data = payload;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    increment(context) {
      setInterval(() => {
        context.commit('increment');
        const newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        context.commit('set_data', newData);
      }, 500);
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  template: `
  <div>{{count}}</div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      d: window.performance.memory.totalJSHeapSize
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('increment');
  },
  watch: {
    '$store.state.data': {
      deep: true,
      handler() {
        this.count = this.$store.state.count;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.1/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
    <div id="app"></div>
```

Но, к сожалению, в моем приложении утечка не исчезла. Но это уже другая история

**Продолжение истории:** В итоге, пришел к выводу, что утечка максимально себя проявляет в дев-режиме. Поэтому у меня 2 *подозреваемых*: сам `vue/vuex` и `vue-dev-tools`, при этом, после иследования срезов памяти, больше склоняюсь к `vue-dex-tools`. Т.к. утечка памяти, сама по себе "пахнет" не очень хорошо, я все равно постарался ее минимизировать. Для этого мне пришлось во всех "тонких местах" (watch, computed, store ...) присвоение объектов делать после их глубокого копирования. После таких манипуляций, в дев-режиме, стала заметна работа сборщика мусора. В конечном счете, объем потребляемой памяти все равно растет, но стали заметны откаты. Что же касается прод-режима, то там стало все замечательно.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю что дело не VUEX, а в компонентах что на него подписаны.
Скорее всего один из их складывает данные в локальную коллекцию или массив и после изменения хранилища не чистит их.

Попробуй отключить все подписки на изменения, компонент за компонентом пока не найдешь.

[image: Понаблюдал некоторое время та примером]