# Тормозит nuxt при нескольких вкладках браузера

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

В режиме dev - nuxt начинает дико тормозить при открытии более 3-4 вкладок. На проде такой проблемы нет. Сам ПК очень мощный, причины в нем быть не может.

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с данной проблемой и как ее решить?

Comment: может поможет - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1075585/%d0%a3%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-vuex